# Return total value from a specific unique id that shares the same description as others item

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having trouble figuring this SQL code out.

The SQL query should return the sum of "things" that the unique id shares with the other items.

The SQL query needs to check if the unique ID shares the same delivery date as the others items and Brand, if it does return the total items for all of them as a summary. So if the unique ID delivery date is 2018-03-28 and brand is Sony (however I dont know what brand it is I need to find out by going to the unique id first), if any other items share this information then return its availability as a whole. so if 5 items share the same information and each of them has 2 availability left it should return 10.

Im using mysql

```
SELECT SUM(COILS)WHERE SELECT MACHINE FROM ORDERS WHERE C_DD="2018-03-28" AND ID="491";
```

Im expecting SUM(AVAILABILITY) to display the total value of the availability of Items that share the same information as the unique ID in this case delivery date and brand.

Problem fixed

```
 SELECT SUM(AVAILABILITY) FROM ORDERS WHERE BRAND=(SELECT BRAND FROM ORDERS WHERE ID="491") AND C_DD="2018-03-28";
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: HI im using mysql

Comment: Is this not as simple as `SELECT SUM(AVAILABILITY) FROM ORDERS WHERE C_DD='2018-03-28' AND BRAND = 'Sony' AND ID='470';`?

Comment: Sorry i reuploaded the code, I dont know what brand it is, thats the problem, i need to go to the unique id find out what brand it is and then check C_DD and BRAND with others items to see if they share the same value

Comment: Problem is fixed see updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you say the problem is fixed, the logic that you describe is better implemented using:

```
SELECT SUM(AVAILABILITY)
FROM ORDERS
WHERE (BRAND, C_DD) = (SELECT BRAND, C_DD FROM ORDERS WHERE ID = 491) ;
```

This assumes that `C_DD` is delivery date.

Comment: Thank you much nicer! :)